# Here api integration react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, here-api

Has anyone tried to use the Here API https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api in a react native mobile app? Can the Javascript of Here api be used in a react native mobile app? I am thinking if this is possible or need to use the mobile SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-heremaps it would lead to a solution for android part only.

Comment: I'll check on it. Thanks a lot!